# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Hardware'

Tags: python, tkinter

hello guys im creating a gui program UBT i have a problem the thing is that i want to use multiple programs and then pass them into others like so:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import variables as v
import functions as f
#Functions :

     #Configuration of the window
root=Tk()
root.configure(bg=v.bg_color)
root.geometry(v.resolution)
root.title(v.title)
     #G.U.I.
         #Message :
message = Label(root, text="Choose your category:", anchor=W,bg=v.bg_color)
message.pack(fill=X)
    #Category Buttons :

frame=Frame(root)
hard_button=Button(frame, text="Hardware",bg=v.bg_color,command=f.Hardware)
hard_button.config()
hard_button.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

that is the one part you see that in the line:
    `hard_button=Button(frame, text="Hardware",bg=v.bg_color,command=f.Hardware)`
in the command I have a f.Hardware command well this is my problem the f.Hardware is another program that i import inside python to keep everything nice and neat.But i have a problem look bellow:

```
import os
import variables as v
import tkinter as tk
import gui as g

def new_hard_window():
     g.root.destroy()

def Hardware():
    new_hard_window()
    hard_path=os.chdir(v.path+"Hardware")
    print(os.listdir(hard_path))
```

I know that one mistake in in the 1st function and the second would be 1st line in the second but i dont know how to fix it. If you would like to run the code in your system then I'm providing also my other file named variables. Thank you guys a lot!!!

```
 path="N:\Python_Programming\Hangman\\"
 bg_color="#FFFFFF"
 resolution="200x90"
 title="Hangman"
```

Feel free to change the path :-P

Comment: I think I  could use something like: `if __name__== '__main__'` inside my functions file __but__ I've never used it before so i don't know how to use it  before and i don't know how to use it. What do you think guys ?

Comment: Is your Hardware class declared on functions module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you run a python file from the command line, it is treated differently by the python interpreter. You can experiment by creating two files in the same directory as follows:

a.py

```
import b
print('Import %s' % __name__)
```

b.py

```
import a
print('Import %s' % __name__)
```

Now if you run `python a.py` you will get:

```
Import a
Import b
Import __main__
```

Why? Because python creates a new module called `__main__` for the file it is executing. The first thing that file does is imports `b`, which imports `a`. Because this time `a.py` is being imported as a module, and not being run directly, python creates a new module for it called `a`. So now you have two modules from the same file, one called `__main__` and one called `a`.

Continuing, `__main__` has imported `b` which has imported `a`. We are now executing in `a.py`. Because `b` has already been imported as `b`, it does not need to be reimported, so we step onto the next line which is to print the name of `a`, and the first line output is `Import a`. Now this file is finished, so we go back to `b`, and output `Import b`. Then that is finished and we go back to `__main__`, which is executing the code in `a.py` (but is a separate module called `__main__`!) and so we output `Import __main__`.

Your problem is that you have a similar circular import: `gui` (which I assume you are running directly from the command line as `python gui.py`) imports `functions`, and `functions` then *reimports* `gui`. However, as for the `a.py` `b.py` case above, actually the first `gui` is loaded into a module called `__main__`, and so when `functions` imports `gui` it creates a new module called `gui` *and then executes all the code in `gui` to populate the new `gui` module*.

So now we have three modules: `__main__`, which is still executing line 4 `import functions as f`, `functions` which is executing line 4 `import gui as g`. So we execute all of `gui.py` to populate the `gui` module, and when we get to line 4, we've already imported `functions` and so we don't re-execute `functions.py`. However, because we're only on line 4 of `functions` *we have not yet created the functions in `functions`, i.e. `new_hard_window` and `Hardware`*. Therefore, when we get to line 19:

```
hard_button=Button(frame, text="Hardware",bg=v.bg_color,command=f.Hardware)
```

`Hardware` **does not yet exist in the `functions` aka `f` module**, because we haven't got onto that line of code yet. So this fails.

Your real problem is that you are trying to use a python file both as a script and as a module *at the same time*. Refactor your code so that the script is only used as a script and not as a module at the same time.