# Python module import works for one file, fails for another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm facing a very strange problem. I've got three files, the first contains the base class, from which the classes in the other two files inherit from.

The strange thing is, everything worked fine yesterday, but one of the files doesn't work anymore today. I haven't touched the imports in the meantime.

```
.
└── orangecontrib
    ├──__init__.py
    └── prototypes
        ├──__init__.py
        └── widgets
            ├──__init__.py
            ├── owpythagorastree.py
            ├── owclassificationpythagorastree.py
            └── owregressionpythagorastree.py
```

So the classification and regression classes need to inherit from the base class, and the imports are done in the exact same way:

*owclassificationpythagorastree.py*

```
...
from orangecontrib.prototypes.widgets.owpythagorastree import OWPythagorasTree
...
```

*owregressionpythagorastree.py*

```
...
from orangecontrib.prototypes.widgets.owpythagorastree import OWPythagorasTree
...
```

Yet when I try to run the two scripts from the command line (with `python owregressionpythagorastree.py`) the regression widget works fine, but the classification widget produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "owclassificationpythagorastree.py", line 6, in 
>       from orangecontrib.prototypes.widgets.owpythagorastree import OWPythagorasTree ImportError: No module named
>   'orangecontrib.prototypes'

This has happened several times in other projects as well, but it eventually sorts itself out. But it bothers me that I don't know what is causing this.

I did try running this both from my regular machine and a python virtualenv, where I have the module installed (I did this with `pip install -e .` in the base directory).

I see no apparent reason for this behaviour and it is bothering me a lot, so any help or insight as to why this is happening and how to fix it would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

As requested, I ran `import sys; print(sys.path)` at the top of both scripts, and after running it through diff, they are both completely identical. Nevertheless, I am posting the results here.

> ['/home/pavlin/dev/orange3-prototypes/orangecontrib/prototypes/widgets',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools_git-1.1-py3.5.egg',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange-bio',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyqtgraph-0.9.10-py3.5.egg',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests-2.9.1-py3.5.egg',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slumber-0.7.1-py3.5.egg',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Genesis_PyAPI-1.2.0-py3.5.egg',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/qt_graph_helpers-0.1.3-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3-prototypes',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python35.zip',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5/plat-linux',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/lib64/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-linux',
>   '/home/pavlin/dev/orange3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-18.7.1-py3.5.egg',
>   '/home/pavlin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Comment: There are `__init__.py` files in each directory. I'll add them to the question, to avoid confusion. This cannot be the issue, since the modules clearly work for one of the files, but not the other.

Comment: I can tell you this, for example if I try to import a module of mine on Desktop, if I try to import it on shell, I can't. Because shell working on another path, but if I import it to a .py file on Desktop, it works. Shell is on the Desktop too, So, try to check them are they actually running on that path. Staying on a path does not mean they are running on that path, that's the trick.

Comment: What about `from .owpythagorastree import OWPythagorasTree`? Or even without the dot?

Comment: That results in a `parent module '' not loaded` error in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought. Have you checked the permissions? Maybe somehow the permissions got messed up and they are giving you the problems.

Comment: The permissions are the same for all the files in the directory, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is a not-complete understanding of how python finds modules.

For an [absolute import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) (i.e. one where you specify the name of the first module such as `import mymodule`, and don't use a period to do a relative import from the package to which the code belongs, such as `from . import mymodule`), the order of lookups is:

1. The current directory.
2. Any directories in `PYTHONPATH` in your environment.
3. Any installed system paths, which may be set in various ways.

To see your complete set of paths to import from, use:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Also, remember that a directory is only importable if it has an `__init__.py` file – you didn't say whether that was the case or not with your code.

Therefore, provided you have the following layout:

```
.
└── orangecontrib
    ├── __init__.py
    └── prototypes
        ├── __init__.py
        └── widgets
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── owpythagorastree.py
            ├── owclassificationpythagorastree.py
            └── owregressionpythagorastree.py
```

I would expect that if you run `python orangecontrib/prototypes/widgets/owclassificationpythagorastree.py` from the base directory `.`, both should work just fine, without needing to modify your `PYTHONPATH`, since python always looks in the current directory for absolutely imported modules first.

If you are running from the `widgets` directory, I would expect it not to work, unless you had first added the base directory to your `PYTHONPATH`.

As a general hint though, except for very small things, you should avoid mixing module code with script code, for exactly these reasons! Make separate python scripts that are designed to be run from a command line, and separate python module code that is designed to be imported. Avoid making modules that can also be run from the command line as scripts.

Comment: Also note that you should seriously avoid situations in which you run script `a.py` which imports `b.py` which in turn re-imports `a.py` – this can lead to really weird things too, see a previous answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35725043/5920499), but I don't think that's your problem in this case, but is another reason why you shouldn't mix module code and script code.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation - I didn't really know how Python imported things, so it has cleared some things up. But unfortunately, this doesn't help me... It is my understanding that since I installed the module to the virtualenv, I could do an absolute import, which works for one file, but not the other. I've also tried running the scripts from all conceivable directories and the result is also the same. Lastly, the only reason I'm running the scripts from the command line is for easier debugging. Interestingly enough, this problem only occurs when running from the command line.

Comment: It seems to me the problem here would be some obscure way python interprets files or something strange like that (I really don't know, hence my question), since the imports are done the same way in both files from the same environment, yet one runs fine, and the other results in an error...

Comment: Maybe check the permissions then as @SirSteel suggests, but I think it's still more likely there's a mistake in your code (experience has shown me that usually it's my code that's got the problem, not that there's some obscure problem with the infrastructure :-)). Could you post the result of `import sys; print(sys.path)` when you put that as the very first thing at the top of the problematic scripts? I would also check that the two scripts don't attempt to import each other or themselves...

Comment: Please see the question for the `sys.path`, unfortunately, they're identical with both the scripts. Also, the two scripts do not interact with each other in any way, the only thing they have in common is that they both inherit from the same base class.

Comment: One final thing I can think of is that you have a problem with old .pyc files lying around in unexpected places. So I would try deleting every .pyc file you can find in all the directories from sys.path. But I'm definitely guessing now! If that doesn't work I recommend that you remove all the installed copies of the code and just start again from the beginning, just using your working copy. Get that to work (which it should immediately), then rebuild your package and progress forward like that.

Comment: I had already tried removing the .pyc files, but that didn't fix anything. Thank you for the help though!