# Import package works for one file but returns error for the other

Tags: python, linux, python-import

Python beginner here, this question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642004/python-module-import-works-for-one-file-fails-for-another), but with no conclusive solution.

I have one file called test.py that is saved on /home/pi, I import firebase package as follows:

```
from firebase import firebase
```

I created another file called test2.py on the same path, tried to import fireabse with the same line of code as above and got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/test2.py", line 1,
>   in 
>       from firebase import firebase ImportError: No module named 'firebase'

I am using Python 2.7.9 on Linux

How can it be resolved?

Comment: You are executing them in the exact same fashion (not mixing `python <script>` and `./<script>`)?

Comment: Yes, I execute them in the same way.

Comment: I can't replicate your error. I mean, I am using python 2.7.9 and installed firebase using pip. But on both files that line just worked. How did you install firebase module ?

Comment: @Gioachino Bartolotta, I think it was it was pip install python-firebase